# Need to log my results to a seperate file

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0

I have this great powershell script I wrote a while back which copy's the users from one Active Directory Group to Another. I need to log the results of each screen output so I have a log of what the script did should there ever be a problem. I would like to write the output to C:\Temp\CopyLog.txt but I can't figure out how to get it to work correctly. I have tried Add-Content and out-file but they don't seem to like me.

```
    Import-Module activedirectory

$string = Get-Content C:\Temp\GroupsToCopy.txt
foreach($i in $string)
{
$split = $i.split(";")
$Source_Group = $split[0]
$Destination_Group = $split[1]

"***Results before script***"

"Current Member's of: $Source_Group"
Get-ADGroupMember $Source_Group | select name | ft -hide
"`n"
"Current Member's of: $Destination_Group"

$Source = Get-ADGroupMember $Source_Group | select name | ft -hide

$DST = Get-ADGroupMember $Destination_Group


if ($DST -eq $null) 
{
"Group has no members"
} 
else
{
Get-ADGroupMember $Destination_Group | select name | ft -hide
}

$Target = Get-ADGroupMember $Source_Group 
foreach ($Person in $Target) 
{ 
    Add-ADGroupMember $Destination_Group -Members $Person.distinguishedname 
}

"`n"
"***Results after script***"
"`n"

"Current Member's of: $Source_Group"
Get-ADGroupMember $Source_Group | select name | ft -hide
"`n"
"Current Member's of: $Destination_Group"
Get-ADGroupMember $Destination_Group | select name | ft -hide
"`n"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Start-Transcript`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx):

```
Start-Transcript -Path C:\Temp\CopyLog.txt -Append
# Rest of script goes here
Stop-Transcript
```